# precision in julia

Tags: julia, bigfloat

I am having trouble working with high precision in julia. I am not able to set a precision of 240 decimal places. I am currently using the BigFloat package, it is the most suitable for me at the moment.

I have this code:

```
epsilon = big(10)^(-240)

a = BigFloat("1.0") + epsilon

println(a)
```

This is my epsilon: `1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000522e-240`there is a small error, "522", but we will disregard it for now.
the problem is that I get `a = 1.0`.
I would like it to be `a = 1+10^-240`

obs. I need to perform several calculations with a high precision, of 250 decimal places, but I am having problems defining this high precision in julia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `setprecision` function with `base=10`:

```
julia> setprecision(BigFloat, 250; base=10)
250

julia> epsilon = big(10)^(-240)
9.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999991631e-241

julia> a = BigFloat("1.0") + epsilon
1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000005
```

Comment: I think doing something like 1//BigInt(10)^BigInt(exp) will be exact (unless floating points are preferred over an exact representation of rational numbers for some reason).

Comment: Yes, this will be exact, but I assumed OP wanted to use `BigFloat` because it will be faster than `Rational{BigInt}`.